# keyerror when referencing dataframe index with date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a datetimeindex as the index.

I am trying to retreive some data with the line below,

> df[row.Index]

But I get "*** KeyError: Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00')

In my dataframe I can see the date exists,

> df.iloc[0]

```
col_1 1.56
col_2 3.4
Name: 2019-12-31 00:00:00
```

And my row.Index gives me,

> Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00')

So why do I get this keyerror when I can see it in my dataframe?

Comment: `df[row.Index]` looks for `row.Index` as a column name, try with loc: `df.loc[row.Index]`

Comment: thanks @Ben.T, can't believe I didn't spot that! thanks for your help if you put it as an answer I will mark it as correct